# Shipping method form in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-methods

In checkout/cart page sidebar listing the Shipping Method, in that, if my shipping is free need to set like "Free" now it displays "$0.00". Please check the attachment and let me know.

Thank you [image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this requirement you need to override two files...

**Step1:** Copy `/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js` to `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/summary/shiping.js` and override `getValue` function alone with below code

```
   getValue: function () {
        var price;

        if (!this.isCalculated()) {
            return this.notCalculatedMessage;
        }
        price =  this.totals()['shipping_amount'];

        if(price < 1){
          return 'Free';
        }

        return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
    }
```

**Step2:** 
Copy `/vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping.js` to `app/design/frontend/[vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Tax/web/js/view/checkout/summary/shiping.js` and override both `getIncludingValue` and `getExcludingValue` function with below code

```
   getIncludingValue: function () {
        var price;

        if (!this.isCalculated()) {
            return this.notCalculatedMessage;
        }
        price = this.totals()['shipping_incl_tax'];

        if(price < 1){
          return 'Free';
        }

        return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
    },

    /**
     * @return {*}
     */
    getExcludingValue: function () {
        var price;

        if (!this.isCalculated()) {
            return this.notCalculatedMessage;
        }
        price = this.totals()['shipping_amount'];

        if(price < 1){
           return 'Free';
        }

        return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
    }
```